# How to convert image deep(CV_8UC3) in opencv?

Tags: opencv

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv){

      Mat img = imread("Nature.jpg"); // Read image from file
      Mat img_chn;

      img.convertTo(img_chn,CV_16UC3);

      imshow("Changed image", img_chn);  //show the changed image
      imshow("Original İmage", img); //show the original image

      waitKey(0); // Wait until user press some key
      return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I see black screen in Changed image window. If I write `CV_8UC3` instead of `CV_16UC3` then no problems happen.

My purpose is to convert 8 bit image to 16 bit image, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is correct.

`img_chn` is correctly initialized, you just can't see it because [imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#imshow) will divide CV_16U images by 256, so your image will appear black (since all values in `img_chn` are `<= 255`).

If you convert the image to `CV_16U` scaling up values from range [0,255] to [0,255*256]:

```
img.convertTo(img_chn,CV_16UC3, 256);
```

you'll see the image correctly.

Comment: thank you, if ı want to convert to 32 bit what must ı write in this? img.convertTo(img_chn,CV_16UC3, ###);

Comment: if you mean float values CV_32F, you need the values to be in [0,1], so `img.convertTo(img_chn, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0)`;

Comment: @Berkay Proper images are 8U, 16U or 32F, and imshow scales displays correctly only these formats. You can obviously have a matrix of 32S, but you need to convert (with proper scaling) to one of the abovementioned formats to display it correctly.

Comment: @Berkay if this answer your original question, please accept it. If you have further question unrelated to this one you should create a new answer. If you're not satisfact with this answer, please let me know